# Using Google Maps to track work per building and allowing users to manipulate that data

Tags: google-maps

I work part time for a political campaign office, who are going door-to-door for several months at a time, all over a city. We need a system to track where we have been, and how long ago we were last there - to be able to know where to visit each week, etc.

Now, I've never done any work with the Google Maps API or MyMaps before, but it does seem like a fairly easy platform for that kind of project. However, my research hasn't given me much to work with.

Is it possible to create a system like this using Google Maps, or would I need to build my own application?

The features I'd need are:

- Placing permanent polygons on top of a map surface, covering individual buildings or blocks.
- Assigning those polygons with a value, indicating when those buildings/blocks were last visited. Perhaps this could be accomplished using color marking?
- Allowing users to modify the "last visited"-variable for each polygon, without allowing them to move or modify the polygons themselves.

This will be an internal system used only by staff, so I'm not worried about security. The access limits are only necessary for making sure that no-one accidentally removes polygons or "last visited"-data.

Can you get me pointed in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Fusion Tables and Google Maps you will be able to keep track of your campaign

Topic Spotlight: Communicating demographics: Examples

[image]

https://sites.google.com/site/fusiontablestalks/stories

**Fusion Mapper** will give you a head start:

http://earth.google.com/outreach/tutorial_fusion_yourowndata.html